# IIS Rewrite Url to another domain/PHP Application and SEO optimisation

Tags: iis, seo, url-rewriting

In my website (asp.net + IIS) i want that url /blog/ be rewritted to my PHP web application hosted in another server.
So www.mywebsite.com/blog is calling www.myblogsite.com without redirecting to It.

Is it possible ? if not is permanent redirection 301 is good prctise for SEO, so google will consider the blog as part of my website

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible**, if you use **iFrames**, **AJAX** etc. but if you are really concerned about SEO than I would say either bring that whole content to your first domain or use " permanent redirection ".

If you use permanent redirection 90-99% ranking power will go to the redirected page. If you want that than it's good.

If you don't want to pass ranking power to that second domain than I would suggest you take that whole content out of that second domain and put on your website under /blog/ and than permanently redirect your second domain(www.blogsite.com) to your /blog/.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to redirect, you want to reverse proxy here. How to do this is:

1. Setup your server to listen for the site on an odd port in the same uri structure, eg -- `http://1.2.3.4:10005/blog`. This is kinda optional -- you can use a hostname. Only gets squirrley if you are using the same host name that you are serving from.
2. Install the Application Requet Routing module on IIS and enable the reverse proxy function.
3. Create a virtual directory on your site at the appropriate sub-uri (eg /blog)
4. In the vdir, add a url rewrite for reverse proxy -- if you did #2 right it should be an option now. Send it back to `1.2.3.4:10005/blog` or whatever you setup.

Things should just work. We've used this to integrate a few popular PHP based CMS apps into sites before with general universal success. Biggest challenge has been that many of those CMS apps really want to know what url they are running at and build absolute links based on that.